# Roslyn TypeLoadException on RenderPartial of ASCX/ASPX in CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, roslyn

I've an mvc cshtml view that has a `RenderPartial` of a `.ascx`.

```
@* Omitted code *@
<div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Vacations/_YearPlanner.ascx", ViewData.Model);}
    </div>
</div>
@* Omitted code *@
```

This always worked until I added Roslyn compiler to the project, since I wanted to use C#6.0 on `.cs` and `.cshtml`.

This made me install two nuggets:

> Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform : 1.0.8
>
> Microsoft.Net.Compilers : 2.3.2 (Latest is: 2.4.0)

I had some problems installing these, until I figured the right combination of versions.

But now, I'm dealing with a problem on this page that renders a legacy `ascx` control.

> The following error occurs:
>       Exception type: HttpCompileException 
>       Exception message: External component has thrown an exception.    at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVirtualPathObjectFactory(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, HttpContext context, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound)    at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Html.RenderPartialExtensions.RenderPartial(HtmlHelper
>   htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)    at
>   ASP._Views_Vacations_RenderDepartmentMap_cshtml.Execute()    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()    at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

This control starts working when I remove the following lines from webconfig:

```
<system.codedom>
  <compilers>
    <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
    <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
  </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

This was added automatically by the package `Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform`.

Do I need to keep this lines? I still need those C#6.0 features.

Do I need to add something to compile `aspx` and `ascx` with roslyn?

**Edit 1**

It works on my machine but not in the server.

**Edit 2**

> - InnerException - External component has thrown an exception.

Comment: It seems version compatibility issue.Please try using Version=1.0.0.0 in both tags mentioned.

Comment: Did you deploy the Roslyn compiler in `bin`?

Comment: What's the `InnerException`?

Comment: @SLaks yes I did. I posted the InnerException on the second edit.